# Sudden Square Wave Transmission

Tags: gpio, radio

I was playing around with korn101's PiNumberStation (found here: https://github.com/korn101/PiNumberStation). It uses GPIO Pin 4 on the Raspberry Pi Model B. I had it working excellently. I had disconnected it and when I went to start the stream back up, it only gave out a square wave and not the message it's supposed to give. I have reinstalled the program AND even Raspbian with no luck and I have NO idea what to Google as GPIO experiments are very foreign to me aside from the basics. I would love some help.

Comment: Does the square wave frequency match the FM frequency? If so it would appear that the problem is with the combination of your info stream and the carrier wave.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's the issue as it seems even the program itself isn't acting as it did before.

Comment: I am not either, but you have not given us much to go on. Have you tried contacting the maintainer or opening a big report?